# In need of an IDE to make an app with a powerful Ui

Tags: android

I'm starting to study mobile development and i want to know what is the best language/IDE to develop an app with a powerful UI. I prefer a android native app over a web one, but it can be an hybrid. I've already tried with C# in visual studio and xamarin, but it looks confusing. I want to build those crazy smooth modern and flat UI apps, so what's the best IDE?

Comment: What about _Google_ ?

Comment: Everything is there is very generic, and almost of the results is about web frameworks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Android Studio for native android development.
[here is the link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

For iOS development use Xcode. You will need a mac computer for this.
[here is the link](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/)

Comment: Java for mobile is good to make a decent interface? I tried to make a application in java for windows once, and it seems limited in this part..

Comment: Are you sure its not you who is being limited with time and efforts?